# System.out.println is not printing out a variable

Tags: java

I am getting this error message

```
finalAmount cannot be resolved to a variable
```

And this is the code in question

```
public class DepositCalculator {

    public static final double annualInterestRate = 1.0;
    public static final int numberOfYears = 5;
    public static final int monthsPerYear = 12;
    public static final int deposit = 1000;
    public static final int depositAmountIncrement = 1000;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(finalAmount);
    }

    public static double calculateAmountNoCompounding(double deposit, double annualInterestRate, int numberOfYears) {

        double finalAmount = deposit*(1+annualInterestRate*numberOfYears);
        return finalAmount;
    }     
}
```

Comment: Yep, the compiler is correct.

Comment: Variables have *scope*. Methods require you to *call them*. I would highly suggest starting with a beginner's book on Java or the tutorials from Oracle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the method

> System.out.println(calculateAmountNoCompounding(deposit, annualInterestRate, numberOfYears));

Comment: I was thinking something like that was the solution, but I didn't think the put in deposit, etc.  Thanks, man.

Answer (score 1):

You try to access a variable method local variable from another method. Check the scope of that variable. Method local variable can be accessed within that method which they were declared only.

`finalAmount` defined inside the `calculateAmountNoCompounding()` method, So, it has a scope withing that method only. You need to print whatever the value returned from `calculateAmountNoCompounding()` not the method local variable `finalAmount`